# ui-router views receives variables

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Currently getting to know ui-router. I have this:

```
$stateProvider
.state('taxonomy', {
    url: '/lista/:taxonomy',
    views: {
        '' : {
            templateUrl: '/js/app/taxonomy/index.tpl.html',
            controller: 'taxonomy.index.controller',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            myClass: 'classForThisOne'
        },
        'sidebarRight@': {
            templateUrl: '/js/app/taxonomy/sidebarRight.tpl.html',
            /* no controller = no variable */
        }
    }
})

.state('taxonomy.detail', {
    url: '/:mode/:taxonomyId?',
    views: {
        'sidebarRight@' : {
            templateUrl: '/js/app/taxonomy/detail.tpl.html',
            controller: 'taxonomy.detail.controller',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            myClass: 'myClassForThisController'
        },

        '': {
            myClass: 'myClassForController taxonomy.index.controller'
        }
    }
});
```

What I would like to be able to do is to be able of the 'myClass' property inside the controller I specified with the `controller` and `controllerAs` variable. Can this be done somehow?

I tried to watch the `$stateChangeStart` event and `$stateProvider.decorator('views', function (state, parent) { })` but without any luck.

Comment: Can you provide a plunkr or fiddle?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/isCh8bEszuJEf6fpJ4yh?p=preview

Roughly.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass through custom data like this:

```
views: {
    '' : {
        templateUrl: '/js/app/taxonomy/index.tpl.html',
        controller: 'taxonomy.index.controller',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        // the 'data' property can be used for custom data
        data: {
            myClass: 'classForThisOne'
        }
    },
```

Then in your controller, inject `$state`, and retrieve the data:

```
function myCtrl($state){
    var myClass = $state.current.data.myClass;
}
```

See for reference: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#attach-custom-data-to-state-objects

Note that above is best practice (use the 'data' object), but you should also be able to do it like you do:

```
views: {
    '' : {
        templateUrl: '/js/app/taxonomy/index.tpl.html',
        controller: 'taxonomy.index.controller',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        myClass: 'classForThisOne'
    },
```

and retrieval:

```
var myClass = $state.current.myClass;
```

Comment: Nah - $state.current.data and $state.current.myClass give me empty (as in 'undefined') values.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried this, but this should work. Write following in your controller:

```
$scope.getClass = function() {
    var currentState = $state.current;
    // Or use any other named view instead of "sidebarRight@"
    return currentState.views['sidebarRight@'].myClass;
};
```

Comment: But I don't know the view's name in the controller, do I. So I would need to hardcode 'sidebarRight@', which I do not want.